# Shift selection, scroll and virtualization in ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, virtualization, itemscontrol

I created a `MultipleSelectionTreeView` inherited from `ItemsControl`, which uses virtualization because of the huge amount of data.

When I select an item in the tree then scroll down and select an other one with Shift key down the items between the two should be selected too.

I use this function to get the next item and I set it as selected later:

```
    internal MultipleSelectionTreeViewItem GetNextNodeAtSameLevel()
    {
        MultipleSelectionTreeViewItem nextNodeAtSameLevel = null;

        ItemsControl parentControl = ParentItemsControl;
        if (parentControl != null)
        {
            int index = parentControl.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(this);
            if (index != parentControl.Items.Count - 1) // if this is not the last item
            {
                var item = ParentControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index + 1);
                nextNodeAtSameLevel = item as MultipleSelectionTreeViewItem;
            }
        }

        return nextNodeAtSameLevel;
    }
```

item is null for me. I know that this is because of the virtualization

Is there any workaround to solve this? Or the only way to create my own virtualizing panel